# Unknown column for com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am trying to connect to MySql database in Spring JPA MVC environment and not able to resolve the following problem.

1) I am trying to fetch data through JPA repository with correct column mapping in entity class but it still promts for wrong column name.

2) To change connection to point to SQL Server do i only need to change the driver? Or anything else is also needed?

Following is my project set up. A bit of over kill but everthing is available here :) Just for reference

Error Trace -

```
Sep 08, 2016 2:26:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [HelloWeb] in context with path [/MySqlConnectionTest] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'devicelogv0_.logAction' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:254)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:247)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.myPackage.service.DeviceLogServiceV2.getDeviceLog(DeviceLogServiceV2.java:47)
    at com.myPackage.service.DeviceLogServiceV2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f469585d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.myPackage.service.DeviceLogServiceV2$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cbae193f.getDeviceLog(<generated>)
    at com.myPackage.controllers.HelloController.printHello(HelloController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Following is my set up -

web.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVCTutorial</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Jpa Entity Manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myPackage" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform">
            <bean factory-method="getDialect"
                class="org.springside.modules.persistence.Hibernates">
                <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring Data Jpa-->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.myPackage"
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        proxy-target-class="true" />

    <!-- hibernate validator -->
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <!-- Connection Info -->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;allowMultiQueries=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="900000" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="180" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com" /> -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myPackage.controllers" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myPackage.service" />


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />


</beans>
```

Controller -

```
package com.myPackage.controllers;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.myPackage.entity.DeviceLogV2;
import com.myPackage.service.DeviceLogServiceV2;

@Controller
public class HelloController{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    @Autowired
    DeviceLogServiceV2 dsv;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "*", "/hello" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      Map<String, Object> searchParams = null;
      List<DeviceLogV2> myList = dsv.getDeviceLog();          
      logger.info("List    --------------------- "+ myList);          
      return "hello";
   }

}
```

Service -

```
package com.myPackage.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.myPackage.entity.DeviceLogV2;
import com.myPackage.repo.DeviceLogDaoV2;

@Component
@Transactional
public class DeviceLogServiceV2 {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeviceLogServiceV2.class);

    @Autowired
    private DeviceLogDaoV2 deviceLogDaoV2;  

    public List<DeviceLogV2> getDeviceLog() {
        List<DeviceLogV2> deviceLogList = (List<DeviceLogV2>) deviceLogDaoV2.findAll();
        return deviceLogList;
    }

}
```

Repository -

```
package com.myPackage.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import com.myPackage.entity.DeviceLogV2;

public interface DeviceLogDaoV2
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DeviceLogV2, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DeviceLogV2> {

}
```

Entity -

```
package com.myPackage.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DEVICE_LOG_V2")
/*@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)*/
public class DeviceLogV2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2926984334474074530L;

    private long id;
    private String logDateTime;
    private String logUserId;
    private String logFullUserName;
    private String logDeviceSerial;
    private String logDeviceModel;
    private String logDeviceMake;
    private String logApplicationName;
    private String logGpsCoordinate;
    private String logType;
    private String logAction;
    private String logArea;
    private String logDetailType;
    private String logDetailHeader;
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 100000)
    private String logDetail;
    private Long logDeviceUserIdFk;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    setters ... getters...
```

and table screenshot - 
[image: mysql Table ref]

Comment: You should investigate Hibernate's `NamingStrategy` for your version of hibernate. There were some changes in Hibernate 5 where you would want to use `ImplicitNamingStrategy`

Comment: i used "ImprovedNamingStrategy" that helped me resolving the issue

Answer (score 0):

All of your column names are uppercase which won't work. You will need to either change your schema to have lowercase column names (`log_action`) or put annotations on your POJO fields like `@Column(name = "LOG_ACTION")`.

You may also be able to find some configuration which will do this automagically.

Answer (score -1):

I see the log write `Unknown column 'devicelogv0_.logAction' in 'field list'`.
But I see the your entity is `@Table(name = "DEVICE_LOG_V2")`.
And maybe you wrote `@Column(name= "logAction")` but column name is `log_action`.
So you must write `@Column(name= "log_action")` or `@Column(name= "LOG_ACTION")`